# how to calculate trigonometric functions (sine,cos,..ect) with result value which is not a float

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, trigonometry, symbolic-math

Back in school I learned that `sin(π/6)=1/2` and `cos(π/4)=1/(√2)` but now in python I only get float results like: `sin(π/6)=0.49999999999999994` and `cos(π/4)=0.7071067811865475` so is there a way to find the value of the result like the first example?
as an equation `a/(b√(c))` , Which a,b,c are variables can be used in python seprated.

Comment: You're probably looking for _symbolic computation_ ([tag:symbolic-math]) or at least something similar. The go-to library for symbolic computation in Python is AFAIK [SymPy](https://sympy.org/) ([tag:sympy]).

Comment: `(sympy.sin(0.25 * sympy.pi) ` --> `sqrt(2)/2` and `sympy.sin( sympy.pi/5)` --> `sqrt(5/8 - sqrt(5)/8)`

Comment: Check the docs for the `fractions` module. The example there is `cos(pi/3)` and you get exactly `1/2`

Comment: @gimix there's no trigonometry functions in [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)

Comment: What I meant is, `Fraction(math.sin(math.pi/6)).limit_denominator()` will give `Fraction(1, 2)` as requested. Admittedly it won't work for `cos(pi/4)` or more complex examples since it will not recognize the square roots